# How to print characters not existing in a font using iText 2.1.3

Tags: unicode, itext

I am writing an application that generates a PDF file using iText 2.1.3. When printing a Unicode text that contains characters not in the font used, the characters simply vanishes in the output.

I have read that the way to solve that is to use a `FontSelector` something like this:

```
public void createPdf(final String filename, final String text)
  throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // Get at document for printing.
    final Document document = new Document(...);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    document.open();

    // Create a FontSelector with multiple fonts.
    final FontSelector selector = new FontSelector();
    final Font f1 = ...; // Covers e.g. Western glyphs
    selector.addFont(f1);
    final Font f2 = ...; // Covers e.g. Chinese glyphs
    selector.addFont(f2);

    // Phrase contains of chunks each using an approriate font
    // for rendering part of the text.
    final Phrase ph = selector.process(text);
    document.add(new Paragraph(ph));

    document.close();
}
```

(Example rewritten from [this](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=214) example.)

However, there might still be some characters in the text that are not covered by any of the available fonts.

Is there a way to tell iText 2.1.3 to print e.g. the Unicode Replacement Character (U+FFFD aka �) for such characters?

Comment: iText 2.1.3 dates from July 2008. That's more than 7 years ago. It is very hard to believe that you are *obliged* to use a version that old. It's obsolete, unsupported, there are technical as well as legal issues with that version of iText. Please be professional thing and upgrade.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I am aware of iText 2.1.3 being a dated version am I would also like to update to a recent version. However, I am still interested in hearing if what I want to accomplish is possible in any version of iText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Unicode Consortium Last Resort Font](http://www.unicode.org/policies/lastresortfont_eula.html) as the last font to search by the `FontSelector` there will be a glyph for every possible Unicode character.

The [Last Resort Font](http://www.unicode.org/policies/lastresortfont_eula.html) is a special font that has different glyphs for different character categories giving a good hint about which kind of characters your font does not support.

So instead of getting � glyphs, the glyphs shown [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/lastresort.html) will be displayed in the PDF.

Comment: I will wait marking my own answer as the solution to give others the possibility to come up with a better answer.